Transferring Universities in Germany Between Intakes (Summer to Winter)
I am an international student from India planning to pursue higher education in Germany. I have a question regarding transferring universities within Germany.
If I enroll in a university during the summer intake, can I apply to another university for the winter intake and transfer there while staying in Germany? Additionally, since I haven't applied for an education loan yet, how would this affect the loan process if I take one in India by showing the name of the university I initially enroll in?
I’d appreciate insights from anyone who has faced a similar situation or has knowledge about the visa, loan, or university transfer process in Germany.
Thank you in advance!

Is this for undergraduate or graduate?

Im looking for graduate Msc

What will transferring do that waiting to start at the other university will not?
